# C# How to update Powerpoint chart without opening Excel

Tags: c#, excel, charts, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint plugin in C# that retreives chart data from a web API and updates a chart in the current Powerpoint slide. This works fine however when I active the chart data Excel opens briefly even though I set the Visible flag to false shortly after. Here is the code:

```
        // Activate the workbook but keep it hidden           
        chart.ChartData.Activate();
        chart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Visible = false;

        // Get the Excel datasheet of the new chart and clear all data
        var workbook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)chart.ChartData.Workbook;
        var datasheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
        datasheet.Cells.ClearContents();

        // Populate the chart with the api data
        // ...
```

Is there any way to set the visible flag on Excel before it opens to prevent this? Or is there another way to feed my data to the chart without using Excel?

Comment: A little context might be nice. What is the type of `chart`? Why are you having to activate it at all? In most automation, you want to avoid `Select()` and `Activate()`.

Comment: It's a simple bar chart. There will be a Powerpoint presentation on screen and the audience watching will take part in a poll using an external web app. I then want to pull in the results of that poll into the Powerpoint presentation as a bar chart. Ideally the presentation will poll the web API and update the chart automatically, however so far I have got to the stage of pressing a button to update the results.

Comment: Ah, I see. However, I doubt you really want to `Activate` the `ChartData`. If the `chart` exists, then `var workbook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)chart.ChartData.Workbook;` should work. No?

Comment: Afraid not. If you attempt to access the workbook without calling ChartData.Activate() then it throws an exception.

Comment: Have you tried to get the data via ADO-Component? We use ADO to import excel-data into our database application. If I remeber well it goes without opening Excel.

Comment: See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789959/update-powerpoint-chart-without-opening-chart-workbook-or-making-it-invisible/50818552#50818552) which shows there is a way to *update* existing chart data without opening the Sheet. I haven't tried it in Presentation mode, though.