# Update PowerPoint chart without opening chart workbook or making it invisible

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub OO()
Dim oPPApp As Object, oPPPrsn As Object, oPPSlide As Object
Dim oPPShape As Object
Dim FlName As String

'~~> Change this to the relevant file
FlName = "C:\Users\lich_\Documents\test.pptx"


'~~> Establish an PowerPoint application object
On Error Resume Next
Set oPPApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oPPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

oPPApp.Visible = True
Set oPPPrsn = oPPApp.Presentations.Open(FlName, WithWindow:=msoFalse) 
Set oPPSlide = oPPPrsn.Slides(2)

With oPPSlide.Shapes("Chart1").Chart.ChartData
.ActivateChartDataWindow

.Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = 0.1231
.Workbook.Close
End With



End Sub
```

As you can see above, I'm trying to edit the chart data in vba.

But since I have control many charts later, I would like to make the workbook invisible ( or not open it at all if possible )

```
With oPPSlide.Shapes("Chart1").Chart.ChartData
.ActivateChartDataWindow

.Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = 0.1231
.Workbook.Close
End With
```

In this code I opened by "ActivateChartDataWindow" method and change the data which I want and Closed.

Is there any way to make the window invisible or to edit data without even opening?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Antonio, take a look at my solution(s) below. While it is sometimes possible to edit existing chart data without opening Excel (examples given in my answer), practically speaking it may not always be possible. In which case, you can *minimize* the Excel window.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thx, I will take a close look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to *update* existing chart data without `Activate` as per @mooseman's answer.

However, if the chart is new/inserted at runtime, as far as I know this cannot be accomplished with interop, as the `AddChart` method adds the chart and simultaneously creates/activates the Excel Workbook. While you may not need to call the `Activate` method, there is no way to *insert* or add a new chart that doesn't involve opening an Excel instance. There is no way around this, this is just how the UI functions and it is by design.

## To Update Data in EXISTING `Chart` / `ChartData`

Below native PowerPoint VBA, but should port easily to Excel with proper reference(s)

```
Sub test()
    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pres As Presentation
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim rng As Object ' Excel.Range
    
    Set PPT = Application 'GetObject(,"PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pres = ActivePresentation
    Set sld = pres.Slides(1)
    Set shp = sld.Shapes(1)
    Set cht = shp.Chart
    
    Call changeData(cht, 6.3)
    
    pres.Slides.AddSlide pres.Slides.Count + 1, sld.CustomLayout
    Set sld = pres.Slides(pres.Slides.Count)
    sld.Shapes.AddChart().Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.WindowState = -4140
    
    Set cht = sld.Shapes(1).Chart
    Call changeData(cht, 3.9)
    
End Sub

Sub changeData(c As Chart, v As Double)
    Dim rng As Object
    With c.ChartData
        Set rng = .Workbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).Range
        rng.Cells(2, 2).Value = v ' etc.
        .Workbook.Close
    End With
End Sub
```

The requirement is to use the `With` block in VBA.

Some brief tests suggest this is also doable via Interop from python using `win32com`:

```python
from win32com import client
ppt = client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
pres = ppt.ActivePresentation
sld = pres.Slides[0]
cht = sld.Shapes[0].Chart
cht.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets[0].ListObjects[0].Range.Cells(2,2).Value = 9
```

And also in C#:

```cs
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

    public static void foo(int value = 10)
    {

        Application ppt = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
        Presentation pres = ppt.ActivePresentation;
        Slide sld = pres.Slides[1];
        Chart cht = sld.Shapes[1].Chart;
        {
            cht.ChartData
                .Workbook.Worksheets[1].ListObjects[1].Range.Cells(2, 2).Value = value;

        }
    }
```

## To Minimize the `ChartData` / `Workbook` Window:

In practice I have not had reliable luck using the `With` method. If you cannot get it to work, then the next-best option is to minimize the window immediately:

```
Sub changeData(c As Chart, v As Double)
    Dim rng As Object
    With c.ChartData
        .Activate
        .Workbook.Application.WindowState = -4140 '## Minimize Excel
        '## DO STUFF:
        Set rng = .Workbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).Range
        rng.Cells(2, 2).Value = v ' etc.
        .Workbook.Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that this method does *briefly* flash Excel on the screen, and this *sucks* because in that brief instant, it can intercept keystrokes/etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer.
Since I'm using Excel vba to control PPT,
The Minimizing Option was the most effective. Thank you so much.
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to activate the chartdata worksheet to make changes to it.

```
 With oPPSlide.Shapes("Chart1").Chart.ChartData
 'this updates the value in the datasheet
    .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = 0.1231 
End with
```

You can also set the chartdata sheet to equal a range in an excel sheet

```
path2 = "C:\JohnDoe\Vasquez_061118.xlsm"
Set xlWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=path2, ReadOnly:=True)
     With oPPSlide.Shapes("Chart1").Chart.ChartData
     'this updates the value in the datasheet
.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B2").Value = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:B3").Value
   End With
```

Comment: Hi, I removed the sentence(.ActivateChartDataWindow
.Workbook.Close) And the error occurs, which is Method 'Workbook' of object 'ChartData' failed

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/chartdata-workbook-property-powerpoint
Here, you can see the remark ( Remarks
Note You must call the Activate method before referencing this property; otherwise, an error occurs.)