# VBA Word: Change Data of charts

Tags: vba, charts, ms-word

I want to change the data of a chart in a Word Document, but I can't find the right way to address my charts. I tried several techniques, but nothing worked. (I´d love to open a ExcelSheet in which I can just change the Data)

So to put it all together: I want to change the data (not the source), of a MS Word chart, which looks like that:

[image: Screenshot of an old chart]

Edit(13.8.):
After request, I try to give you some "reference Code" to work with.

```
Sub ChangeChart()
Dim aktDocument As Document
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim SourceSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set aktDocument = ActiveDocument    
Set SourceSheet = aktDocument.Shapes(1).Chart.OpenSourceData 'I know it´s not that easy

SourceSheet.Range("B5") = newStuff

aktDocument.Shapes(1).Chart.SetSourceData = SourceSheet

End Sub
```

I know this may sounds utopic and ridiculous, but I just don´t know, how to address the chart in the right way, or to even work with it properly.

Edit(15.08):

Even after recreating the old charts, the following code is not able to find a shape which has a chart. And therefore it stops when the index is out of range.

```
Sub Test()
  i = 0
  Do While i < 100
    i = i + 1
      If ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).HasChart Then
         MsgBox "found one!"
      End If
  Loop
End Sub
```

Solution(30.08.):

The answer from @Cindy Meister was the solution to my problem. After further working with it, I came to the problem, that the ChartData always opens on the screen, while running the code.

Just for reference this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50789959/10071300) was my workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Office applications use the Excel engine to create and manage charts. In Word, charts can be formatted in-line with the text or with text wrap formatting. In the former case, a chart object needs to be addressed via the `InlineShapes` collection, in the latter via the `Shapes` collection.

Since your sample code uses `Shapes(1)` I've used that in the code snippet below. If it's not certain that the first `Shape` in the document is the chart, but you've assigned the `Shape` a name, you can use that as the index value (for example `Shapes("MyChart")`. Or you can loop the Shapes collection and check `HasChart`.

`HasChart` returns True if the `Shape` (or `InlineShape`) is a Chart. It's then possible to set `Shape.Chart` to an object variable. The chart's *data* can be accessed using `Chart.ChartData.Activate` - if you don't use `Activate` it's not possible to access the data when the chart's worksheet is stored in the Word document. Only then can `Chart.ChartData.Workbook` return a workbook object, and through that the worksheet can be accessed using `ActiveSheet`. From that point on, it's like working with the Excel object model.

```
Sub ChangeChart()
    Dim aktDocument As Document
    Dim shp As Word.Shape
    Dim chrt As Word.Chart
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, SourceSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Set aktDocument = ActiveDocument
    Set shp = aktDocument.Shapes(1)
    If shp.HasChart Then
        Set chrt = shp.Chart
        chrt.ChartData.Activate
        Set wb = chrt.ChartData.Workbook
        Set SourceSheet = wb.ActiveSheet
        SourceSheet.Range("B5").Value2 = newData
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sadly I had to recreate the charts, which I wanted to edit. It seems like they were just outdated. But afterwards, your solution worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. Were the charts made with MS Graph, then? I could have given you the code for that if you'd provided the information...

Comment: I don´t how they were created, they were from an old Report, which I did not create. That's why it was so hard for me to work with it.

Comment: I very sorry, but the problem is still not solved `:D I tried to use a test code today and there seems to be no shape with a chart in it, but that should be impossible. Can you help me out again? I´ll place my code in a new edit.

Comment: Does the chart have text wrap formatting? Or is it "in line" with the text? If the latter, you need the InlineShapes, not Shapes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was on vacation last week. The InlineShapes seems to be the right ones! My test program was able to open the ChartData Workbooks. Now I´ll try to integrate, what I've learned in the real Makro. Thanks a lot, my problem should be solved now.

Comment: Great @Jandos :-) I mention `InlineShapes` in my answer (first paragraph), but do you think it needs more emphasis, based on your experience with the answer content?

Comment: No, I did everything according your answer and in the moment I used the right collection everything worked fine. You gave me all the right tools, but I walked down the wrong trench. As soon as you send me in the right one everything was clear:D And again, all my thanks to you!